# Conversion to logical from sym is not possible

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the path length for a ray incident on a toric surface but i get the following error message

"Conversion to logical from sym is not possible."

"Error in cal_path (line 188)
        if Const>Const_Prev"
Can someone suggest a way to help solve this error?
The actual code is below

```
         %Conic Toriodal surface
         %This calculates the path length of a ray from a point to the surface

         P=[0 0 40];
         X=P(1);     % define the start point
         Y=P(2);
         Z=P(3);

           Dir=Dir/norm(Dir);

           S_o=-P(3)/Dir(3);
           S_f=0;
           S_Prev=-100;
           S=0;

           k=1;
           X=X+S_o*Dir(1);   % define the point intersect with the z=0 plane
           Y=Y+S_o*Dir(2);
           Z=Z+S_o*Dir(3);   % here Z=0

           X_1=X;
           Y_1=Y;
           Z_1=Z;

           Cx=1/25;              % Curvature of surfaces, 1-by-(j-2) vector, c=1/R
          Cy=1/10;

          syms x y z
          f=z-(Cx*x^2+Cy*y^2+(k*Cy-Cx)*(Cy*y^2./(1+sqrt(1-k*Cy^2*y^2)))^2)/(1+sqrt(1-            Cx*(Cx*x^2+Cy*y^2+(k*Cy-Cx)*(Cy*y^2./(1+sqrt(1-k*Cy^2*y^2)))^2)));
          %the function of the surface F(x,y,z)=0%


          diff(f,x); % calculate the differential of x
          diff(f,y); % calculate the differential of y
          diff(f,z); % calculate the differential of z

          N=0;
          while abs(S-S_Prev)>=0.0000000001  
          N=N+1;

          Const_Prev=abs(S-S_Prev);

         S_Prev=S;

         F_x=subs(diff(f,x),[x,y,z],[X,Y,Z]);  % the coordinate x of the normal vector of   the surface at P
        F_y=subs(diff(f,y),[x,y,z],[X,Y,Z]);  % the coordinate y of the normal vector of the surface at P
       F_z=subs(diff(f,z),[x,y,z],[X,Y,Z]); % the coordinate z of the normal vector of         the surface at P


      q=(Cy*Y^2./(1+sqrt(1-k*Cy^2*Y^2)));
      G=(Cx*X^2+Cy*Y^2+(k*Cy-Cx)*q^2);                                                 
       F1=z-G/(1+sqrt(1-Cx*G));
       F2=F_x*Dir(1)+F_y*Dir(2)+F_z*Dir(3);

       S=S-F1/F2;

       Const=abs(S-S_Prev);

       if Const>Const_Prev
        path='Out';
        return
      end

      X=X_1+Dir(1)*S;
      Y=Y_1+Dir(2)*S;
      Z=Z_1+Dir(3)*S;

      abs(S-S_Prev)   



      if ~(isreal(S_f))
      path='Out';
      return
      end
      end
```

Comment: try: `if double(Const)>double(Const_Prev)`

Comment: Can you post a [minimal working example](http://sscce.org/) which I can copy/paste to reproduce your problem. After generating a lot of dummy-inputs I finally got your error message. When I look at `Const`, I get an expression in terms of `x` and `y` - it does not evaluate to a single value, hence it cannot be converted using `double` and it cannot be evaluated in the `if`-statement.

Comment: Thank you.This is a working example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I assume `Dir = [0 0 1]`
2. Before it is evaluated as part of the `if`-statement, `Const` has the following value:

   ```
   Const = 
       abs(z)
   ```

   This can be obtained by using the debugger and placing a [breakpoint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-182).
3. Apparently, `z` has not been substituted throughout your evaluation.
4. You use `subs` when defining `F_x`, `F_y` and `F_z`, but when you define `F1`, you still use `z`. Instead, use:

   ```
   F1=Z-G/(1+sqrt(1-Cx*G));
   ```

   Now, `Const` should take on a value and be free of symbolic expressions.